# Derby app created using 'derby new test' not working

Tags: derbyjs

I've installed derbyjs using `npm install -g derby` and then created a test app using `derby new test`.

Then i started the app using `node server.js` and I got the following output:

```
info  - socket.io started
Starting cluster with 1 workers in undefined mode
`kill -s SIGUSR2 7161` to force cluster reload
Go to: http://localhost:3000/
info  - socket.io started
```

So I tried to request `http://localhost:3000/`, but the site does not finish loading and I get the following exception:

```
TEMPLATE ERROR
Error: Model mutation performed after bundling for clientId: 79f4a9f3-25fc-438d-b9f4-a450dccf9566
at Model.errorOnCommit [as _commit]   (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/bundle/bundle.Model.js:64:9)
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/txns/txns.Model.js:120:15
at next (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/middleware.js:7:26)
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/txns/txns.Model.js:107:16
at next (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/middleware.js:7:26)
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/txns/txns.Model.js:101:16
at next (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/middleware.js:7:26)
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/txns/txns.Model.js:92:16
at next (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/middleware.js:7:26)
at Object.run (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/middleware.js:10:12)

events.js:68
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: Cannot write after end
at Gzip.write (zlib.js:311:31)
at ServerResponse.res.write (/web/derby/test/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/compress.js:82:18)
at Object.View._render (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/lib/View.server.js:337:9)
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/lib/View.server.js:276:10
at Array.2 (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/lib/View.server.js:300:5)
at Object.Promise.resolve    (/web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/node_modules/racer/lib/util/Promise.js:21:19)
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/lib/View.server.js:136:17
at /web/derby/test/node_modules/derby/lib/files.js:224:7
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:308:15)
at process._makeCallback (node.js:248:20)
```

I have absolutely no idea how I can get it running... Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

I've created a bug report on the derby repository: https://github.com/codeparty/derby/issues/170

Comment: @downvoter: Thx for your opinion. Would you help me to ask this the 'right' way?

Comment: Did you ever get any insight into this?  I've installed node 0.10.1 & derby 0.3.14 on a couple machines and got this same "Model mutation performed after bundling" message as soon as I connect, trying to run the "holler" app on the derbyjs front page.

Comment: I read your ticket and see the problem went away for you.  On linux, I moved down to node v0.8.9 and all the examples worked for me.